# How to navigate url using pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am learning on how to use pushState to navigate url to the exact placement. When click on the button, url changes to 'upload' but does not navigate to the url page. This is what i tried;

home.html

```
<button onclick="loadUpload()">Upload Page</button>
<div id="upload"></div>

<script>
function loadUpload(){
  history.pushState({}, "", "/upload/");
  document.getElementById("upload");
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **entire** point of `pushState` is that it **doesn't** trigger navigation. It is a mechanism for saying "I am changing the state of the DOM using JavaScript, the resulting state is the same as you would get if you visited this URL" (while making the back and forward navigation buttons built into the browser work).

If you want to **navigate** with JavaScript then assign a new value to `location.href`.

```
location.href = "/upload/"
```

However, since your JavaScript doesn't do anything **except** navigate, you should just be using a regular link for this in the first place:

```
<a href="/upload/">Upload Page</a>
```

Comment: @Quentin...thanks for your explanation. I'm trying to navigate to upload.html without page reload. What is the better way of doing this? Can you help with a code.

Comment: You can't go to a different page without loading it.